# Liferay: Can we create deployable site template?

Tags: liferay, portlet, sitetemplate

I'm quite new in liferay and this must have been a very basic question.

Can we make site templates deployable as standalone component like themes? If yes how can we do this? Any help or content explains how to do this will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can export and import site templates - they'll not be deployed like themes, but you can carry them from one portal to another. Check the cogs-icon in the top-right of the Site Template configuration screen in Control-Panel and you'll find the Export/Import Actions. The individual SiteTemplate's Action button also has an Export option available.

Another option is to get familiar with Liferay's API (learn ServiceBuilder for understanding the concepts) and examine the sourcecode. A good starting point is the ancient [7cogs sample code](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) (not all will compile as-is, this article is for an older version, but the principles will help you to understand). Also note that the article links a second follow-up article. *Everything* in Liferay is done through the API and you can literally automate everything - you'll "just" have to find the proper API and use it.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf for quick hint on where I can start from. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Site templates can be deployed in a plugin via the use of Liferay's Resources Importer.

See: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/themes/-/knowledge_base/6-2/importing-resources-for-your-theme for more information.

You can probably find some some examples here: https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/category/15828894